# Manim doesn't produce video

Tags: python, manim

When running `scene.py` (taken from the Community Manim docs):

```
from manim import *

class CreatingMobjects(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        circle = Circle()
        self.add(circle)
        self.wait(1)
        self.remove(circle)
        self.wait(1)

class VectorArrow(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        dot = Dot(ORIGIN)
        arrow = Arrow(ORIGIN, [2, 2, 0], buff=0)
        numberplane = NumberPlane()
        origin_text = Text('(0, 0)').next_to(dot, DOWN)
        tip_text = Text('(2, 2)').next_to(arrow.get_end(), RIGHT)
        self.add(numberplane, dot, arrow, origin_text, tip_text)
```

with `python -m manim scene.py CreatingMobjects -p -ql`, everything works fine and the movie pops up as it should.

However, if I run the command `python -m manim scene.py VectorArrow -p -ql`, it doesn't work, with the error: `.../partial_movie_file_list.txt: Invalid data found when processing input` and `the file .../VectorArrow.mp4 does not exist.`

Why does the first scene output a video but not the second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `self.wait(1)` after the `self.add(numberplane, dot, arrow, origin_text, tip_text)`.
Then script should work.

Comment: OMG...that worked!  I don't know why I didn't think to try that.  Thank you.  I got these examples directly from the Community Manim docs, so I would have thought they would work "as is."